# VueJS2: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm creating very simple `Popup Modal` Using `Vuejs2` and `TailwindCss`. However i encounter the error like below, when i'm tring to click on `Button`..

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.

**`In Parent Component`**

```
// CardModal

<template>
    <div class="bg-white">
        <div v-if="showing">
            Modal
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showing: false,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**`Child Components`**

```
<button  @click="showing = true" class="px-4 my-4 mx-3 bg-blue-400 py-1 font-bold rounded text-white">
    Add Product
</button>

<!-- Modal -->

<cardModal :showing="showing" />

// Script

    props: {
        showing: {
            // required: true,
            type: Boolean,
        }
    },
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand your code but you can't change value of prop in your child component directly instead you can emit an event to your parent which change the value of prop for you.

e.g your child component which has

```
<template>
 @click="$emit('show',true)"
</template>
//
 props: {
        showing: {
            // required: true,
            type: Boolean,
        }
    }
```

your parent

```
<cardModal :showing="showing" @show="showing=$event" />
```

Comment: No modal pop up...

**Edit:** tried `console.log(this.showing)`, its return `false`